# jquery traverse through row getting span class and title

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

I have a table each row has an id and several td's containing spans

e.g

```
<tr id="row"><td><span class="first name">myfirstname<span class="surname">mysurname</span></td><td><span class="street">mystreet</span><span class="town">mytown</span></td>
```

What I wan't to do is when passed a rowid traverse the row and create a key value array of the span classnames and the span values.

currently I can go find each thing individually which is very cumbersome.

Comment: the code is incomplete, you missed a </tr> end tag

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla  and `</span` in the first `<td>` ...

Answer (score 2):

Your markup should be fixed a bit:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>
            <span class="first name">myfirstname </span>
            <span class="surname">mysurname</span>
            </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="street">mystreet</span>
                    <span class="town">mytown</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You didn't close the `<span>` and `<tr>`
    ​

**CODE:**

```
function getSpansData(rowId) {
    var map = {};
    $('#' + rowId + ' span').each(function() {
        map[this.className] = this.innerHTML;
    });

    return map;
}

getSpansData('row1');
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H88sb/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
function traverseRow(id) {
    var arr = {};
    $('td span', 'tr#' + id).each(function() {
        arr[this.className] = this.innerHTML;
    });
    return arr;
}

traverseRow('row');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send a code sample to have more accurate responses. Try this:

```
var values = new Object();
$("#row").filter("td span").each(function(){
    values[$(this).attr("class")] = $(this).text();
});
alert(values.surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = {};
$("#row_id td span").each(function() { 
  map[$(this).attr("class")] = $(this).html(); 
});
```

Comment: You don't need to assume it, the question tag is `jQuery`!

Comment: @gdoron I just saw the question not the tag.But your comment is right. I have removed the line from the answer.